# How to make C# button click only one time and make a textbox show two result?

Tags: c#, wpf

I write below simple code. I want to make this happen:
 1. Click button.
 2. Show the first string.
 3. Wait for 3 seconds.
 4. Show the second string.
But with this code, i can only see the second string after i click the button and wait for 3 seconds. i can't see the first string. is there any way to make this happen?

```
namespace clicktest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = "Show 1st time";
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            this.textBox.Text = "Show 2nd time";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alexander Higgins said, you can use ***await Task.Delay***, but you have to add the *async* type to your method, like this:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox.Text = "Show 1st time";
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    this.textBox.Text = "Show 2nd time";
}
```

Comment: yep, missed that.

Comment: The other benefit of this async method is that it allows the UI to remain responsive.  If you don't care about that (or actually want it to lock-up for user input, eg prevent the user from jumping-in and editing that text), you can add `this.textBox1.Refresh();` before the `Thread.Sleep()` function, which serves to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking a thread, such as when using `Thread.Sleep`, in WPF prevents the GUI from refreshing.

Instead you can use `await Task.Delay` which won't block the thread:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox.Text = "Show 1st time";
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    this.textBox.Text = "Show 2nd time";
}
```